# What should my ip and port no. be so that errno 10061 doesn't arise?

Tags: python, sockets

Server code:

```
import socket
import base64

filename = open("received.xvid","ab")

TCP_IP = '127.0.0.1'
TCP_PORT = 5005
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
s.listen(1)

conn, addr = s.accept()
data = conn.recv(16)
filesize = int(data)
iter = filesize//BUFFER_SIZE
i = 0

while (i < iter):
    data = conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
    filename.write(data.decode('base64'))
    if not data:
        continue
    i = i + 1

data = conn.recv((filesize - (iter*BUFFER_SIZE)))
filename.write(data.decode('base64'))
filename.close()

conn.close()
```

Client code:

```
import socket
import time
import base64

TCP_IP = '127.0.0.1'
TCP_PORT = 5005
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024

filename = open("test.xvid","rb")
MESSAGE = base64.b64encode(filename.read())
filesize = '%16s'%len(MESSAGE)

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
s.send(filesize)
time.sleep(1)
s.send(MESSAGE)
s.close()
```

When I run the client code, I get "socket.error: [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it". I don't understand why. What should I put in place of TCP_IP and TCP_PORT to make the code work?

This is what I get when I enter the command netstat -tnl.

Displays protocol statistics and current TCP/IP network connections.

NETSTAT [-a] [-b] [-e] [-f] [-n] [-o] [-p proto] [-r] [-s] [-x] [-t] [interval]

-a            Displays all connections and listening ports.
  -b            Displays the executable involved in creating each connection or
                listening port. In some cases well-known executables host
                multiple independent components, and in these cases the
                sequence of components involved in creating the connection
                or listening port is displayed. In this case the executable
                name is in [] at the bottom, on top is the component it called,
                and so forth until TCP/IP was reached. Note that this option
                can be time-consuming and will fail unless you have sufficient
                permissions.
  -e            Displays Ethernet statistics. This may be combined with the -s
                option.
  -f            Displays Fully Qualified Domain Names (FQDN) for foreign
                addresses.
  -n            Displays addresses and port numbers in numerical form.
  -o            Displays the owning process ID associated with each connection.
  -p proto      Shows connections for the protocol specified by proto; proto
                may be any of: TCP, UDP, TCPv6, or UDPv6.  If used with the -s
                option to display per-protocol statistics, proto may be any of:
                IP, IPv6, ICMP, ICMPv6, TCP, TCPv6, UDP, or UDPv6.
  -r            Displays the routing table.
  -s            Displays per-protocol statistics.  By default, statistics are
                shown for IP, IPv6, ICMP, ICMPv6, TCP, TCPv6, UDP, and UDPv6;
                the -p option may be used to specify a subset of the default.
  -t            Displays the current connection offload state.
  -x            Displays NetworkDirect connections, listeners, and shared
                endpoints.
  -y            Displays the TCP connection template for all connections.
                Cannot be combined with the other options.
  interval      Redisplays selected statistics, pausing interval seconds
                between each display.  Press CTRL+C to stop redisplaying
                statistics.  If omitted, netstat will print the current
                configuration information once.

Comment: Are you running client and server on the same machine?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that the server process is running?  Start the server and then enter the command `netstat -tnl` in a shell window and post the results, UNEDITED.

Comment: When I run the server and client on the same machine, things are fine. When I run them on different machines, that is when the problems arise.

Comment: @Zack I posted the results.

Comment: @Iguana Eegh, that was not the information I was looking for.  Sorry about that; I think we're on different operating systems.  But I think I know what's wrong, anyway; I've answered the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I run the server and client on the same machine, things are fine. When I run them on different machines, that is when the problems arise.

OK, I know what your problem is.

```
 TCP_IP = '127.0.0.1'
```

You have hardcoded this IP address into server and client.  It is a special IP address that means *this machine and only this machine*.  When you use it in `bind()`, the server listens for connections *only* from the same machine.  When you use it in `connect()`, the client tries to connect to a server running on the same machine.

To listen for connections from *any* machine, as is probably your intention for the server, you call `bind` with the special IP address `0.0.0.0`.  (A *complete* server for production use needs to do something slightly more complicated than this, but that is enough for a test program like this one.)

To have a client connect to a server running on another machine, it needs to take the DNS name of the other machine as a command line argument, and run that through [`getaddrinfo`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.getaddrinfo) to get the IP address to connect to.

You should purchase and read [*UNIX Network Programming, Volume 1, 3rd Edition*](https://www.powells.com/biblio/61-9780131411555-1) and [*Advanced Programming in the UNIX Environment*](http://www.powells.com/biblio/2-9780321637734-0).  They are expensive, but they are worth it.  They will flesh out the above advice and teach you many other things which you need to know if you're going to write a complete network server or client.  (Make sure to get the third edition of *UNIX Network Programming*; earlier editions contain a bunch of obsolete junk you don't need to know about.  The second volume of *UNIX Network Programming* is also valuable but not as applicable to your current situation.  *Advanced Programming...* is also less immediately relevant, particularly if you are on Windows, as I suspect you are from the phrasing of the error message.)

Answer (score 2):

- If this happens always, it means that the machine exists but that it
  has no services listening on the specified port, or there is a
  firewall stopping you.
- If it happens occasionally and retrying succeeds, it is likely
  because the server has a full 'backlog'.

When you are waiting to be `accept`ed on a listening socket, you are placed in a backlog.  This backlog is finite and quite short - values of 1, 2 or 3 are not unusual - and so the OS might be unable to queue your request for the `accept` to consume.

The backlog is a parameter on the `listen` function - all languages and platforms have basically the same API in this regard. This parameter is often configurable if you control the server, and is likely read from some settings file or the registry.  Investigate how to configure your server.

*Regardless* of whether you can increase the server backlog, you do need ***retry*** logic in your client code to cope with this issue as even with a long backlog the server might be receiving lots of other requests on that port at that time.

There is a rare possibility where a NAT router would give this error should it's ports for mappings be exhausted.  I think we can discard this possibility as too much of a long shot though, since the router has **64K** simultaneous connections to the same destination address/port before exhaustion.

Also check here for more causes:

- [No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.](http://www.smartftp.com/support/kb/connection-refused-f58.html)